# object oriented programing function call js

Tags: javascript, oop, tampermonkey

I have a problem because calling the function works in DevTools, but not in Tampermonkey

In DevTools this works, it returns a string

```
g.worldConfig.getWorldName()
```

but in Tampermonkey I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'worldname')
const worldName = g.worldConfig.getWorldName()
console.log(worldName);
```

I checked and when I add proto, the function is displayed but I can't call it anyway

```
const worldName = g.worldConfig.__proto__.getWorldName
```

```
getWorldName() {
  return _classPrivateFieldGet(this, _config).worldname;
}
```

Comment: that means `_classPrivateFieldGet(this, _config)` is `null`. Why? You haven't posted the code to determine that

Comment: The error means that `g.worldConfig` is `null`. Without seeing how you set this, it's impossible to say why.

Comment: getWorldName() {
    return this.#config.worldname;
  }

Comment: Apparently `this.#config` is null when called from Tampermonkey. Don't know why. Probably due to the way in which `g` or `g.worldConfig` is created.

Comment: a solution would be to wait until it's not null.  preferably using a proper event, but also polling could work.

Comment: Try a different `@sandbox` mode.

Comment: Perhaps `g` or `g.worldConfig` are simply not there on page load, and are added at a later point. You could test for that with a `setInterval` - let it run in intervals of, for example `100ms`, and let it output `typeof g.worldConfig` to the console.